# How to make the Delphi IDE show the Windows taskbar when it's set to automatically hide?

Tags: delphi, ide, taskbar

I have my Windows Taskbar set to auto-hide. Is there a way to have the Delphi IDE, running in window maximized mode, unhide the taskbar when the mouse pointer reaches the bottom of the screen?

If I turn off the taskbar "auto-hide" feature there's no problem accessing the taskbar items when the Delphi IDE is running in window maximized mode. I prefer to keep the task bar hidden until the mouse approaches the bottom of the screen and have it automatically appear. I've looked around at the options within the Delphi IDE and cannot find a setting that would allow an "auto-hide" taskbar to display.

Am I missing something?

Embarcadero QC Bug Report:
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34329

Comment: This is a bug in RAD Studio. Might be related to RAD Studio's customized window frame or title bar. (This is like the 1000th time I am proven right when I say "don't custom-draw window frames or title bars or controls unless you absolutely know how Windows works and you can *guarantee* that it won't introduce bugs under special circumstances".) So probably the only thing you can do is to file a bug report at https://quality.embarcadero.com.

Comment: (Nitpicking, so that Google will find this page using the right keywords: you don't run the IDE in full-screen mode, but with the IDE window *maximized*.)

Comment: A good workaround is to set focus to the task bar using the keyboard. Just press Win+T.

Comment: Taskbar auto hide is the worst UI ever

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But it is optional and not the default so it doesn't hurt much. Besides, it cannot be the worst UI ever, since Aero Shake clearly is much worse.